# how to use directive as filter?

Tags: angularjs, filter

I have to seperate lists with data that I would like to filter with the same directive:

```
  .directive('myFilter', function ($filter) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'my-dialog.html',
            link: function ($scope) {
                $scope.lov_state = [
                    {'lookupCode': 'AL', 'description': 'Alabama'},
                    {'lookupCode': 'FL', 'description': 'Florida'},
                    {'lookupCode': 'CA', 'description': 'California'},
                    {'lookupCode': 'DE', 'description': 'Delaware'}
                ];
            }
        };
    });
```

The page looks like this:

```
  <my-filter></my-filter>

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in data | filter:address.state">
      {{item.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>


  <my-filter></my-filter>

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in data2 | filter:address.state">
      {{item.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

At the moment the filters work on  both the ul's? What do I need to update to make sure the filters work both lists independently?

plunkr:http://plnkr.co/edit/eNgvIJwhNAXrizR4yevc?p=preview

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you are trying to accomplish. Sorry Plunkr doesn't really work on mobile.

Comment: really not clear what you are trying to do. Your directive has isolated scope and isn't in same scope as ng-repeat. Please explain in more detail what objective is

Comment: Trying to filter the data in the ul below the my-filter directive. The filter filters on id which should match the selected one in either the data or data2 collections.

Comment: @Leeuwtje That's still very unclear. I fail to see any relationship between the uls and the directive. And the filter doesn't filter on id. It filters on address.state.

Comment: @charlietfl this directive does not have an isolate scope. It would if the returned object has a `scope: {...}` field.

Comment: @JBNizet which it did when comment was made. Had isolated scope and variation of question was `doesn't work`